# Need a SQL command for these tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 2 tables (student and attendance):

```
mysql> describe student;
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| student_id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| student_email        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| student_phone_number | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_first_name    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_last_name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_email         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_phone_number  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| days_absent          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| days_tardy           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| class_id             | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe attendance;
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| student_id      | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| class_id        | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| attendance_date | date       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| absent          | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tardy           | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| note            | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to check the attendance and email of all the children who are absent or tardy for the day. Is there a SQL statement I can use that can, for example, select the students from attendance with an absent/tardy value = 1, then using that student_id specified in the attendance table, pull all the student info from the student table where attendance.student_id = student.student_id?

Comment: looks like you are using mysql. Are you also looking for a solution for SQL Server ?

Comment: It was just mysql. I accidentally tagged sql-server.

Comment: Are you familiar with JOIN clause?

Comment: check `JOIN` sintaxis http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm relatively new to MySQL, so I'm learning as I'm going along. I can check out that w3schools link that Juan Carlos Oropeza posted.

Comment: A good place to practice JOINs is SQLZoo. com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try exists

```
select student_email,student_phone_number from student std
where exists(
select 1 from attendance atd where std.student_id = atd.student_id
and (atd.absent =1 or atd.tardy =1)
)
```

just make sure you select all the info from student table and exists all the filter in attendance talbe. the condition is student_id.

Also if you need info from attendance talbe, then use join.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking one quick question, that'd be swell. In your statement where you have "select 1 from attendance". What exactly is the function of the 1 here? is it referencing the same "1" from tardy/ absent, or is it limiting the selection to only 1 student?

Comment: @Bob_Danelou pls check out mysql's documentation on exists subqueries for an answer.

Comment: @Bob_Danelou this 1 you can replace with anything,'1','0' or even null.it's not a function, it's the syntax for exists. the subquery of exists is alwasy return a true or false.